# Practices For Anandamaya Kosha? Happiness

Tags: gods, mantras, practice, meditation

Is there any practice to be in Bliss, Joy - आनन्द . Practices to nourish Anandamaya Kosha.
What are practices / mantras recommended to someone in Depression.. Always Sad or Irritated..

Who Is God of emotion, happiness or Mood

Comment: You are conflating two different concepts. The Ananadamaya Kosha is when the Atman (Brahman) is covered in upadhis and associates Itself with the individual jiva. The Blissful Self is when the Atman is not associated with the individual jiva.

Answer (score 1):

Bliss, joy, anand, happiness are different grades of feeling satisfied and showing it.

A kindergarten child comes running to the parent and shouting that she got "good" in her page or slate from her teacher. This is happiness for that child.

The same grown up child is not happy with "Good" from the professor. The youngster wants "Excellent" to be happy.

A lady feels bliss when she experiences repeated orgasms but still be unhappy because it is not from her husband whom she loves immensely.

This is a comparative emotion.

I have presented the Mantra to get rid of depression or inner turmoil.

OM NAMA SHIVAY, or
OM ACHYUT ANAND GOVIND

Recite till the depression / sadness vanishes from your mental attitude.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the questioner seems to know as to how help attain happiness. And it is perhaps in this context he seems to have used the  Anandmaya Kosh. It is in this context that I wish to reply. In view of illuminating comments by #Sw Viswanand it seems inconceivable of practicing Blissful sheath. But blissful sheath through its expression of deep sleep has immense cannotation and divine message for the mankind. The wonderful experience of oneness and Nih-Shesh Dukh ( Conspicuous by absence of sorrow)  is the natural experience. The state of deep sleep, the expresion of blissful sheath has been greatly  eulogized  by the so many Mantras of Br Upnishad   to quote a few( 4:3:6 to4:3:32) as the means for realisation of Pure Consciousness in Oneself. The cannotation in itself is a great insight for pursuing the path of self upgradation. The practice of beholding oneness in infinite names and forms may be the means to attain the seamless happiness. To start with even seeing oneness in the human 
 fraternity could be quite helpful. Please do note Existence, Consciousness, desire for happiness are common to the mankind. They all take the same oxygen the same food provided by mother earth. Such examples of commoness abounds. 
As regards the question of God of moods and attitude Geeta ch 7 slola   12 is the direct reply. It is Lord Krishna Himself  ! Regards, Hare Krishna

Comment: The above referred  slola reads as -- Ye chaiv sattvika  bhavaa rajsaastamsashch ye! Matt eveti taanvidhhi na tvaham tesu te mayi  !!

Comment: when quoting a source, add the verses in your answer...you are also are conflating different terms and concepts. The anandamaya kosha is not the deep sleep state, which is Prajna. Prajna is referred to as the third quarter of Brahman. The state of Bliss, of the Atman, is the fourth quarter - the Turiya.